# how can i edit openssl sign function using php?

Tags: php, openssl, signature

i want to add the signature, returned by the `openssl_sign` function,
to a file  in the same process of signature.

---

the problem is : when i add the signature to the file after signing it, i get an error while
verifying the signature with the `openssl_verify` function.

```
openssl_sign($current, $signature, $pkeyid);
```

i want this $siganute to be added in the $current file, and this file should be signed with the same signature in the same process, i know it's a little bit confusing.

Comment: You have to remove the signature from the file before verifying its contents. Otherwise you will always get `File was tampered` errors.

Comment: thanks for your comment.
but sorry for not giving all details concerning the file . 
the file is a PDF and i add the signature with FPDI ,so is it possible to remove the signature or the text i added in my PDF ?

Comment: This works only if you keep the signed hash separately from the PDF itself - otherwise you need specialized tools for embedded PDF signature. Look https://raymii.org/s/tutorials/Sign_and_verify_text_files_to_public_keys_via_the_OpenSSL_Command_Line.html

Comment: i will check that ;
thanks for your help